# how to use rs.syncFrom for initial sync?

Tags: mongodb

I want to setup a new secondary for a replica set, but I don't want it sync from the primary for performance reason, so I try to use the `rs.syncFrom` command.

before I run `rs.add` in the primary (for the new secondary), the newly setup secondary cannot call `rs.syncFrom`, it output error say `rs.initiate` was not called. But when after `rs.add` is called, it begins initial sync.

and from [the doc](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-replica-set-secondary-sync-target/),

> To affect the sync target for the initial sync, run rs.syncFrom() operation before initial sync.

please help~

Answer (score 3):

This is confusing in the docs, but there's a short window (~30 seconds) of time between when a host is added to the replica set, and when the initial sync happens. You can tell when a client has started initial sync due to a log entry like:

```
Mon Mar 24 10:21:21.231 [rsSync] replSet initial sync pending
Mon Mar 24 10:21:21.231 [rsSync] replSet syncing to: XXXXX:27017
```

The steps I follow:

1. Open a mongo shell to new-host and your replica set primary.
2. On primary: `rs.add("new-host:port")`
3. ASAP On new-host: `rs.syncFrom("preferred-host:port")`

I often execute step 3 a few times because it is a no-op outside of the effective window and the window can be tricky to hit (as you've discovered).

Reference on the Mongo Google Group: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mongodb-user/msOFZrj5TKk/e7huENWhiQoJ

Comment: On newly added host (Secondary) it says, "not authorized on admin to execute command { replSetSyncFrom:"

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is a simpler way to achieve this, in case your replica set isn't too big. You can use `iptables` to temporary block outbound mongo traffic to your primary and, probably, other members of replica set, except a secondary member you want to become a source of initial sync. After adding a new member to a replica set on primary with [`rs.add`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/rs.add/), you need stop **mongod** process on this secondary node and add `iptables` rules, like this:

```
 iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d primary_ip --dport primary_port -j DROP
```

where `primary_ip` - is an IP address, and `primary_port` - is TCP port used by mongod process on a primary node. After starting **mongod** process, the initial sync source will be chosen based on MongoDB [chained replication](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-chained-replication/) policy.

In a similar way you can create temp block for other replica set members, or
block all outgoing mongo traffic except of your initial sync source member.

Answer (score 0):

Add an entry to the hosts file on the new secondary which points the hostname of the current primary to the IP of an existing secondary you wish to sync from.

Restart mongod on the new secondary after adding the hosts entry and before the `rs.add()`.

When the initial sync is done, remove the hosts entry and restart mongod.